# Is it OK to use css optimizers to before to make site live?

Tags: asp.net, css, sitecore

Is it OK to use [css optimizers](http://www.printradar.com/2009/11/25/25-online-css-compressors-to-optimize-your-styles/) to before to make site live. When we can't to any other server side compression techniques (gzip, combining, sass, less etc)

I want to make CSS file short and readable. How to use these tools without loosing css functionality. what options we should use and what not.

Have you used any? Which is best tool and why?

Comment: Why can't you use server-side compression? No access to the server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want short and readable css, I would highly recommend checking out something like [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [less](http://lesscss.org/).

CSS optimizers are usually there to bring down the file size of the css file so less is getting pushed over the wire (unfortunately, that tends to mean the file becomes unreadable)

Personally, I use sass relgiously, and have a build task that calls out to YUI compressor to compress my css (and javascript) files before they get deployed.

Comment: Ok but i can't use sass in my case

Answer (score 1):

Are you using rails? if you are, you can use [bundle-fu](http://code.google.com/p/bundle-fu/).

it basically squishes all your stylesheets together on the fly. You don't have to worry anything getting broken.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Sitecore and therefore using IIS, you can also see if you've setup Content Expiration.

For Sitecore it can be good to setup Content Expiration for the Sitecore folder (around 7 days is good), you can also set it up for css & js folders.

Setup is done here: [IIS 6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx?mfr=true), [IIS 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/07/10/iis7-how-to-enable-content-expiration.aspx)

Hope this also helps, even though it isn't exactly what you were asking about.